# How to run a python file from another file without displaying any output or waiting for it to finish

Tags: python

I have a program 2test.py which at one point wants to execute 1test.py. I would like to make it such that (a) the script is executed without waiting for output and (b) there is no output displayed from the second script.

Here are my working examples:

2test.py

```
import subprocess
import os
print("starting")
subprocess.Popen(["python3", "1test.py", "-s" ">", "/dev/null 2>&1"])
print("done")
```

1test.py

```
import time

print("Printed immediately.")
time.sleep(2.4)
print("Printed after 2.4 seconds.")
```

Ideally, 2test.py is some loop that sometimes calls on 1test.py.

The desired behaviour is:

```
~/testing$ python3 2test.py
starting
done
~/testing$
```

but what I get is:

```
~/testing$ python3 2test.py
starting
done
~/testing$ Printed immediately.
Printed after 2.4 seconds.
```

Does anybody know how to get that?

Comment: There is no shell by default in `Popen` so you can't use shell commands like `>` or `&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct the output to `/dev/null/` via `subprocess.Popen`:

```py
subprocess.Popen(["python", "1test.py"], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```